# React Native UseState Array Clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have the following code - the idea is to create an animated polyline (for a map). I found some stuff in the internet, but it was with the "old" methods/without `useEffect`, `useState`...
I can´t clear the `polylinePath` array in the `else` - I am trying to print out the current length, but it always returns the initial state length from `props.Direction`. Can you help me? I have no idea why my AnimatedPolyline isn´t working.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

export default function AnimatedPolyline(props) {
  const [polylinePath, setPolylinePath] = useState(props.Direction);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      animatePolylineStart();
   }, 70);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [props.Direction]); //tried [], too

   const animatePolylineStart = () => {
      if (polylinePath.length < props.Direction.length) {
         const Direction = props.Direction;
         const polylinePathTemp = [
            ...Direction.slice(0, polylinePath.length - 1)
         ];

         setPolylinePath(polylinePathTemp);
      } else {
         setPolylinePath([]);
      }
   };
      return (
         <Fragment>
            {
               (polylinePath.length > 0) && <Polyline
                  coordinates={polylinePath}
                  strokeColor="#484848"
                  strokeWidth={5}
               />
            }
         </Fragment>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in use effect when you use an empty array as a dependency it will never move so use effect will be called only one time (like componentDidMount). so here use effect should depend on Direction.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    animatePolylineStart();
 }, 70);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [props.Direction]);
```

Comment: It hasn´t changed anything - still returns the same length. `setPolylinePath([]);
         console.log(polylinePath.length);` and it won´t render.

Comment: how the value of props.Direction is changing over time?

Comment: props.Direction is not changing at all it´s a array with fixed coordinates. polylinePath should change over time so the line could be rendered point after point.

Comment: #edit if I refresh (auto save) for like 10 times I can see the line and then when I keep refeshing I can animate the line.

Comment: I think you should start with an empty array for the first time : useState([]); so it will enter in the if `polylinePath.length < props.Direction.length`

Comment: I thought about that already, too. So the line is rendering every time now, but I have to refesh myself every time to have a "animation". So with every refresh I add/remove the next part from the line.

Comment: I created a simple sandbox with your code, it seems to work for me https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-meninsky-sp9sx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

return setPolyLinePath([]) in useEffect method

```html
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
       clearInterval(interval);
       setPolyLinePath([])
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I tried that - nothing changes. Still have to "auto-save-reload" to have a change. No animation.